# How to reduce padding in X-Range charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to reduce overall height of my X-Range chart, I see the most obvious way to do this is by reducing overall padding on the Y axis around each series.

Using the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/x-range/) as an example, I have tried various properties such as adding `groupPadding: 0`, `pointPadding: 0` and other parameters but none seem to take effect.

[image]

Comment: I have been setting the `height` of the `#container` to `200px`. It made the chart lower in height. Is this what you have been trying to achieve?

Comment: `groupPadding` and `pointPadding` have no effect because you set `pointWidth`, so the sizes are computed *in pixels* from the container height taking into account the value you set. Leave it to the default `undefined` and the others will work as expected, their values being interpreted *in real space*, i.e., 1 unit per bar/group [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt9y7gjp/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce padding you can use groupPadding and pointPadding or pointWidth but you can't use both at the same time. As suggested by [@kikon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16466946/kikon)

However, if you want to reduce the overall height of the chart, you can style the chart container as [@BennyCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451634/benny-code) wrote or set the chart height with `chart.height`.

```
chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    height: 250
},
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gq6kw1rd/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.pointWidth 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.pointPadding